# Count of selected checkboxes inside a nested repeater

Tags: jquery, repeater

I need to find the count of selected checkboxes which are inside a nested repeater in Jquery. My code as follows:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="myRepeater" OnItemDataBound="myRepeaterBinding">
  <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="internalRepeater" OnItemDataBound="internalRepeaterBinding">
    <input class="chkToCompare" type="checkbox" runat="server" id="xxxx" />
  </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In my button click i am writing inside a function like:

```
var boxes = $('#' + '<%= myRepeater.ClientID %>').find($('.chkToCompare'));
var checkedLength = (boxes.filter(':checked').length);
alert(checkedLength);
```

But checkedLength is always 0. Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: What is length of boxes?

Comment: Length of boxes is also 0

Comment: I believe selector u using in first (JS) line is not correct. or You are running js code before dome ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ASP.NET repeater doesn't emit any wrapping markup. Unless you explicitly add one, there is no element in your rendered HTML that has an ID that matches the output of `<%= myRepeater.ClientID %>`.

Your counting method works fine, as seen in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqx9t/).

You just need to wrap the outer repeater with an element you can find in your DOM:

```
<div id="checkboxContainer">
    <asp:Repeater ...>
        ...
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

And then look for that:

```
var boxes = $("#checkboxContainer .chkToCompare");
```

Answer (score 0):

use your repeater inside a div with fixed id

```
<div id="repeaterContainer"></div>
```

And on using Repeater you use `<thead></thead>` and `<tbody></tbody>` html tags to include header and body and use your check boxes to count or the items of repeater inside `<tbody></tbody>` tags.
And then on your button click event

```
var count=0;$("#repeaterContainer table>tbody>tr").each(function (i, elem) {
                var tr = $(this); if(tr.find("input[class=chkToCompare]").is(":checked")){count++;}}); alert(count);
```

This should work.